# How to make windows authentication to authenticate based on the user instead of the machine?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, iis, connection-string

I'm trying to make my web application to authenticate using windows authentication, but when i add `Integrated Security = True` in my connection string instead of authenticating using the user name it instead uses the machine name.
I dont know if i making myself clear but here are some images of the actual problem.

So here is the image of my connection string code on webconfig
[image]

but using this the aplication tries to authenticate using my machine name as shown here:[image] (CEBI\INFODSKT003$)is my machine name , but i wanted it to use the name of the user logged. can someone help me here? thanks,

Comment: What you look after is called **impersonation**. Assuming your app uses Windows Authentication and you impersonate your app pool identity, you'll get what you want. There are multiple resources on impersonation available, also here at StackOverflow: https://www.google.pl/search?q=app+pool+impersonation#spf=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same network user for your site, regardless of the user using your website, you need to set your website's application pool to run as a network user.

You can do this by opening the IIS manager, selecting the app pool and clicking **Advance Settings...** under the Actions pane menu.  Select **Identity** and then click the button beside the current user listed.  Select **Custom account** and click Set.  Use the format `domain\username` for the username and enter the password for the user.

If you want each of your websites user to access the database, each with its own network user name, then take a look at [ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I believe this answer could be wrong as this will make the pool run under **one fixed** account. I believe what the OP rather thinks of is a way to get the identity of the user currently running the browser. Take a look at my comment under the question.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Updated accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.